# How to recognize first report opening in fastReport's code section

Tags: pascalscript, fastreport

I have a report with drilled down sections. I can open it by click on section or selecting «expand all»/«collapse all» command in context menu. But I also want to open or close all this sections outside the report, then I pass status that I want into report as a variable and write in «code» tab command to manage state of this sections. But then commands «expand all» and «collapse all» doesn't work, because when I select one of this command, it cleaned up all script variables and execute all code sections again.

How can I made code section, that run only once and not rerun when it rebuilding because user interacts with report?